# Count unique numbers in CSV (PowerShell or Notepad++)

Tags: powershell, csv, notepad++

How to find the count of unique numbers in a CSV file? When I use the following command in PowerShell ISE

```
1,2,3,4,2 | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```

I can get the unique numbers but I'm not able to get this to work with CSV files. If for example I use

```
$A =  Import-Csv C:\test.csv | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
$A.Count
```

it returns 0. I would like to count unique numbers for all the files in a given folder.

My data looks similar to this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
5,,7,4
0,,9,
3,,5,4
```

And the result should be 6 unique values (preferably written inside the same CSV file).

Or would it be easier to do it with Notepad++? So far I have found examples only on how to count the unique rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following (PSv3+):

```
PS> (Import-CSV C:\test.csv |
      ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.properties.value -ne '' } |
        Sort-Object -Unique).Count
6
```

- The key is to extract all property (column) values from each input object (CSV row), which is what `$_.psobject.properties.value` does;
- `-ne ''` filters out empty values.
- Note that, given that `Sort-Object` has a `-Unique` switch, you don't need `Get-Unique` (you need `Get-Unique` only if your input already *is* sorted).

---

That said, if your CSV file is structured as simply as yours, you can speed up processing by reading it as a text file (PSv2+):

```
PS> (Get-Content C:\test.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
      ForEach-Object { $_ -split ',' -ne '' } |
        Sort-Object -Unique).Count
6
```

- `Get-Content` reads the CSV file as a line of strings.
- `Select-Object -Skip 1` skips the header line.
- `$_ -split ',' -ne ''` splits each line into values by commas and weeds out empty values.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`Import-CSV C:\test.csv | Sort-Object | Get-Unique`:

- Fundamentally, `Sort-Object` emits the input objects *as a whole* (just in sorted order), it doesn't *extract property values*, yet that is what you need.
- Because no `-Property` argument is passed to `Sort-Object` to base the *sorting* on, it compares the custom objects that `Import-Csv` emits *as a whole*, by their `.ToString()` values, which happen to be *empty*<sup>[1]</sup>
  , so they all compare the same, and in effect no sorting happens.
- Similarly, `Get-Unique` also determines uniqueness by `.ToString()` here, so that, again, all objects are considered the same and only the very *first* one is output.

---

<sup>[1] This may be surprising, given that using a custom object in an *expandable string* does yield a value: compare `$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ foo ='bar' }; $obj.ToString(); '---'; "$obj"`. This inconsistency is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163).</sup>

Comment: nice, a very well laid out & written answer. It's a pleasure seeing your contributions under the 'PowerShell' tag.

Comment: I appreciate the nice feedback, @AdamParsons.